# can command substitution in a POSIX shell be used only in place of a command name?

Tags: shell, posix

The POSIX shell standard at

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04

says in section 2.6.3:

```
Command substitution allows the output of a command to be substituted in place of the command name itself
```

This would seem to imply that it is only guaranteed to work, if you substitute for the whole command name; if you substitute for a part of it, or something else, then it may or may not work.

Experimenting:

```
$ echo ;

$ $(echo echo) ;

$
```

So far so good...

```
$ e$(echo cho) ;

$ echo $(echo ';')
;
$ echo $(echo foobar)
foobar
```

The first and third example above seem to "work" but the second "does not work".  Is this all simply undocumented and random behavior, as the standard seems to imply, and in reality for some other POSIX shell, none of these three are guaranteed to "work"?

(By "work", I mean "produce the same result as if the results of the substitution were typed in the command itself on the terminal")

Comment: In the second and third examples, the command is `echo` and that is _not_ the result of command substitution.  Only the arguments to the echo command are the result of command substitution.  Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes;  and according to the standard, this is not guaranteed to work, is that right?  By "work", I mean, produce the same result as if the result of substitution were simply typed in the command itself.

Comment: Did you intend to write `$(echo foobar)` in place of `echo $(echo foobar)`?

Comment: @John1024 No;  I just wanted to illustrate the situation, where command substitution yields not the whole command _name_ (which the standard says it supports), but a command _argument_ - which the standard, it seems, is not guaranteed to support, but here it "worked"

Comment: Command substitution can be freely used to create command _arguments_.  That is the normal usage for command substitution.  Using it to create a command name is the unusual case.

Comment: I just read the POSIX doc on command substitution and, you are right, it gives the impression that it is to be used to create command names.  That is just poor writing.

Comment: Run all of your examples with tracing turned on (`set -x`). There is nothing strange going on here, AFAIK.

Comment: Can you please clarify why are you assuming that the second "does not work"? What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: @thread I did - it's in the text of the question.  The "expect" part, well, that's tricky - strictly speaking, this is undocumented, so there is no expectation as such. I am just trying to see, what is guaranteed to occur and in what situations.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you think the second example "does not work".  You pass a semi-colon as an argument to echo, and it prints it.  Perhaps you expect it to work as if you had done `eval echo $(echo ';')`, which would call echo without passing it an argument.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this:

```
$ echo $(echo ';')
```

Does not output the same as this:

```
$ echo ;
```

Is the same reason why this:

```
$ ;
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
```

Does not output the same as this:

```
$ `echo ';'`
;: command not found
```

The latest case, the output from command substitution (the (?)*expected-to-be*(?) token `;`) is interpreted as a command, because it is passed [and interpreted] as a command in a subshell, and not as a command interpreter built-in token.

As my interpretation, this isn't against the standard.

**EDIT: Answering the question**

You stated:

> This would seem to imply that it is only **guaranteed to work**, if you
>   substitute for the **whole command name**; if you substitute for a **part of
>   it**, or something else, then it may or **may not work**.

And the POSIX standard states:

> The shell **shall expand the command substitution** by executing command
>   in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) **and
>   replacing the command substitution** (the text of command plus the
>   enclosing "$()" or backquotes) **with the standard output of the
>   command**, removing sequences of one or more `<newline>` characters at the
>   end of the substitution.

The standard seems clear regarding to what happens. This is not a question of what's present in a command containing a command substitution, only the command that's inside the enclosing `$()` or or ``.

Comment: thank you, but IMHO you did not answer my question, but a different one

Comment: @MarkGaleck Editted with the relevant part of the standard regarding the distinction of what what command it refers to (not to what's outside the `$()` but to what's inside).